# Hacking Attempt Requests Not showing Up on Webserver Logs But Google Analytics Shows it

Tags: webserver, tools

Which hacking tool makes a request and does not show up on web-server logs?

`/en/latest/` has been requested over 116, we don't have this URL on the website at all!

The request to that URL does not show up on web-server logs but I setup google analytics to track ad-blockers by loading the script on a different URL that ad-blockers don't know . But ever since i setup this google analytics it has trapped lots of hacking request on none existing URL?

How comes google analytics captures the request(The Hackers don't actually know) and the request seems not reach the web-server because no logs are shown?

The thing is there is a deliberate request to none existing URL, that don't show up on web-server logs, but my secrete google analytic scripts captures the URL

Comment: There are lots of reasons why things might not be logged. Do you use a CDN? How is your logging configured? Rule out server-based things before jumping to hacking tools. Have you manually tested going to `/en/latest/` to see if it shows in your logs?

Comment: Yeah I use a CDN cloudflare, when I visit /en/latest/ i can see the page very well and it's a 404 and the web-server logs it. And each day I see those request in google anlytics happen several times in a day.